# Trying to change directory for UltiSnips snippets

Tags: vim, code-snippets, snipmate, ultisnips

What is the correct way to change where UltiSnips searches for snippets. I tried this in my `~/.vimrc` with no success:

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = "/newfolder/snippets/"
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["UltiSnipsNewDir"]
```

Answer (score 5):

first one just use the full path like ex:

```
let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = "~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/UltiSnips"
```

Comment: thank you. in the end decided to not mess around with the directory configuration and just have automated backups of my snippets from default directory into location I want. I was just concerned about location where I am backing things up from.

Comment: `let g:UltiSnipsSnippetsDir = "~/.vim/bundle/ultisnips/UltiSnips"` should be added to your `~/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

First add this line to `.vimrc` file:

`leg g:UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories=["FolderA","FolderB"]`

Then put your snips under folder:

`~/vim/bundle/vim-snippets/FolderA`

Notice: the middle path should be "**vim-snippets**" not "**ultisnips**" if relative path is used, because the snippets are separated from the engine, it's another plugin **'honza/vim-snippets'**.

BTW, `UltiSnipsSnippetDirectories` is where ultisnips searchs snips, `UltiSnipsSnippetsDir` is where to save snips when you type `:UltiSnipsEdit` to create a snip.